# How can I toggle a bootstrap modal without using a button?

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

It works perfect, toggling my bootstrap modal with a button (the id of the modal is "exampleModal"):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

How can I just call the toggle method without this button? I have a flask/jinja for-loop that gets executed/rendered when there are errors. I'm try to achieve something
like that:

```
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    exampleModal.toggle() <-- how can I achieve this?
{% endfor %}
```

In the bootstrap javascript API documentation it says `$('#myModal').modal('show')`, but I cannot find out what is the correct syntax to call it in my template.

Answer (score 0):

It's done using JavaScript in Bootstrap 5. jQuery is no longer required.

```
var modalPopup = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("exampleModal"), {});
modalPopup.show();
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/5auLZltXJW)

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't still completely work. In `{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}` I write your suggest lines in a function `myFunction`, and I can call the function by button `<button type="button" onclick='myFunction()'>Click Me!</button>`, that works. But when I just put `<script>myFunction()</script>` inside the for-loop, the function never gets called. That is strange, because the button works, and for example `<script>alert(123)</script>` gets executed, but not `<script>myFunction()</script>`.

Comment: myFunction() would need to be called

Comment: But why does `<script>alert(123)</script>` work, and `<script>myFunction()</script>` does nothing?

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/p/T875Mm6tTP
I modified your example. Can't get `<script>myFunction()</script>` to work.

Comment: Please accept this as it answers your question *"How can I toggle a bootstrap modal without using a button?"* Again it works fine when you actually call the function: https://www.codeply.com/p/EIttomqL5r